# Как правильно перебирать элементы изменяющегося массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, динамические-массивы, итераторы

Почему `false` не удалилась, но `""`  — удалилась?

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(e) {
    if(e ==  false || e == '') {
      arr.splice(arr.indexOf(e), 1);
    }
  });
  console.log(arr);
}

bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

То, что получилось:

> [7, "ate", false, 9]

Comment: вам не кажется несколько сомнительным факт удаления элементов массива внутри цикла по его перебору? обычно если такое делают, то перебирают массив с конца, что бы удаление элемента не влияло на индексы последующих перебираемых элементов. зы: чем `filter()` вас не устроил? зы2: индекс элемента параметром коллбэка передается, его не надо искать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы циклом проходите от первого элемента к последнему, и когда вырезается один из элементов - индексация смещается. Правильно в таком случае проходить циклом в обратном направлении

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {    
      let e = arr[i];
      if(e ==  false || e == '') {          
          arr.splice(i, 1);
      }  
    }
    
    console.log( arr )
}
bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

Или использовать какую-либо функцию по фильтрации элементов массива, например [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что Вы итерируетесь по массиву, который изменяете в процессе итерации, изменение порядка следования элементов даст обратный результат, полюбуйтесь:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(e){
        if(e ===  false || e === '') {
            arr.splice(arr.indexOf(e), 1 );
        }
    });
    console.log( arr )
}
bouncer([7, "ate",  false, "", 9]);
```

Если Вы хотите отфильтровать массив, на это есть специальный метод:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
    arr=arr.filter(function(e){
        return e !==  false && e !== '' 
    });
    console.log( arr )
}
bouncer([7, "ate",  false, "", 9]);
```

или просто

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
    arr = arr.filter(e => e); // оставить только все не false значения (не NaN, "", 0, false)
    console.log(arr)
}
bouncer([7, "ate",  false, "", 9]);
```

Ну или воспользуйтесь циклами, как в другом ответе

Answer (score 1):

Так происходит потому что Вы удаляете из массива который перебираете, в результате элементы массива смещаются! Можете копировать массив! и удалять из него:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    var newArray = arr.slice();
    arr.forEach(function(e){
        if(e ==  false || e == '') {
            newArray.splice(newArray.indexOf(e), 1 );
        }
    });
    console.log( newArray )
}
bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```